Eternal sound problem in Ubuntu 20.04
I get a hissing sound after some minutes of turning on the computer. This problem comes back every single time I format my PC. I live with this issue in Ubuntu for years, since I bought my PC. I usually change some settings on pulseaudio file (I think it is the battery saver, not sure I usually change multiple options), and it stops, but this time this workaround is not working as it used to.
The hissing sound happens both on my headset and monitor.
This last time I changed my pulseaudio settings file the hissing does not happen out of nowhere (after using the PC for some time), but there are 2 new problems:

It is impossible to turn off system sounds even after putting system sounds on mute. They sound awful, kind of low and sizzling, really annoying. Similar to the constant hissing sound.


If I change any configuration on the sound options in settings, the hissing starts. Also, if I unplug and plug my headset the hissing starts.


I have an AMD processor, an NVIDIA 1060 GTX graphics card, and Ubuntu 20.04. I tried going for 22.04 but the amount of bugs is even worse on GNOME, some configuration changes permanently crash the OS.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I see no way of doing that. I mentioned two issues because they are probably due to the same reason.
